# how to design RESTful API for html selection

Tags: rest

I am a beginner in web development. Now I am develop one application based on RESTful API and Angular framework. I'm confused about the selection resource API design.

For example, when user create sales orders, he will see a select control which can list all available customers. But the user may have no permission to manage customers. The same thing happend in customer cases creation.

Should I build two customer select API endpoints for orders and customer cases? What is the usual practise?

Comment: Please post some code that you have tried.

Comment: I use python flask as API server, there is the order API endpoints: `order-list` for get order list or create new order, `order-detail` for get order detail or update order, `order-selection-customer` for order customer selection, `order-selection-salesman` for order salesman selection, `order-selection-payment` for order payment term selection, `order-selection-product` for order product selection. The `*-selection-customer` has created in many places, such as orders, order billings, customer cases, promotions, reports etc.